# Spin-lattice relaxation calculation

Tags: vasp

I am trying to calculate the spin-lattice relaxation time using VASP DFPT(`ibrion=8`).
I have got the `Hessian matrix`.
Is it possible to get the $\tau_1$ from the Hessian?